# TYPO3 groupedFor viewhelper according to dates

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have a simple model "item" with 3 properties:
title, description, date

Now I want to have a list like this:

**10.10.17:**

title item 1

title item 5

**12.10.17:**

title item 8

and so on

According to [groupedFor - grouping objects according to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369572/groupedfor-grouping-objects-according-to-dates)

I added a getter like

```
/**
 * Get day month year of datetime
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getDayMonthYearOfDatetime()
{
    return (int)$this->datum->format('dmy');
}
```

My list view:

```
<f:groupedFor each="{items}" as="dayMonthYearOfDatetime" groupBy="dayMonthYearOfDatetime" groupKey="datum">
                <tr>
                    <th>{datum}</th>
                </tr>
                <f:for each="{dayMonthYearOfDatetime}" as="calendar">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{item.title}</td>
                    </tr>
                </f:for>
            </f:groupedFor>
```

Now I get the following output:

**101017**
title item 1
title item 5

**121017**
title item 8

How to diplay the correct date "10.10.17" instead "101017"?

If I change my getter to:

```
    return (int)$this->datum->format('d.m.y');
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return (int)$this->datum->format('d.m.y');
```

Remove the `(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect to have a grouping if you return `int` from a date-string with dots.

Either you need to return string (but I don't know whether the function is allowed to return anything else than int) or you need to calculate your datestring from the *calculated* integer.

Try a viewhelper which does integer caclulations ( % 100, / 100 %100, /10000) or simple substrings (,0,2 ,2,2 ,4,2) to extract the values for day, month, year for a following concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the real date object of the first group-item.

So it would be

```
<f:format.date format="d.m.Y">{dayMonthYearOfDatetime.0.datum}</f:format>
```